# Upload array of dictionaries to server and then download

Tags: ios, download, upload, nsmutablearray

I'm currently working on a video editing part where I capture the screenshots and some key values in dictionary. At the end when recording is done, I've an array of dictionaries.

Now I want this array of dictionary to upload to a server and later I want to download that array.

I've tried converting `NSMutableArray` to bytes and write it into text file and then I download the text file and convert it back to `NSMutableArray`.

The issue is that the dictionaries inside that `NSMutableArray` do not have key values.

Any other better way to upload and download this information on a server?

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: Why don't you convert your array into NSData? Post it on server and after downloading you can convert your data back into JSON so that you can easily parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate your infomation and images.
Then upload them.

There an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//------------------This part is for upload------------------
//Upload info
UIImage* sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"source.png"];
UIImageView* imgV1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
imgV1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
imgV1.image = sourceImage;
[self.view addSubview:imgV1];

NSDictionary* uploadDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"source.png",@"testImage",
                           nil];
NSData* uploadData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:uploadDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString* uploadString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:uploadData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Upload image
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"source.png"];
[self uploadInfoToURL:uploadString andImageData:imageData];
//-----------------------------------------------------------

//------------------This part is for upload------------------
//Download info
NSString *downLoadString = uploadString;
NSData* downLoadData = [downLoadString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *downLoadDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:downLoadData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
UIImageView* imgV2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 250, 100, 100)];
imgV2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:imgV2];

//Download image
NSString* downURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://youServer/%@",[downLoadDic objectForKey:@"testImage"]];
imgV2.image = [self getImageFromURL:downURL];
//-----------------------------------------------------------
}

-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {
NSLog(@"Begin download");
UIImage * result;
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
return result;
}

-(BOOL *) uploadInfoToURL:(NSString *)infoString andImageData:(NSData *)data {
NSLog(@"Begin upload");
//Use http post to upload your image data to you server
//    if (nil == error) {
//        return YES;
//    }
return NO;
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: There can be hundreds of images in one go